# modify current algorithm - APSP

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I have the below APSP algorithm:

[image]

This computes the shortest path. The length of the path is the sum of weights of edges of path.

How can i modify the above algorithm in order to compute the shortest path where length is the weight of the heaviest edge on this path.

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: this looks more similar to [widest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem), except, as pointed out by Yevgeniy, it should use max instead of min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 7th line instead of

```
cost = D[i, k] + D[k, j]
```

you just should put

```
cost = Max(D[i, k], D[k, j])
```